# Why do I need minecraft to be open for this code to run?

Tags: python, minecraft, python-sockets

So this code gets **minecraft server status** and for most servers it works perfectly (*such as hypixel*), but in **Aternos** servers (*a free minecraft server hosting website*) it only works if you have minecraft open and refreshing every once in a while in the multiplayer menu.

- Why is this happening?
- Is it possible to fix it and if yes how?

Note: *this code is not written by me and I can't find who I got it from so I can't fully understand it*

May help: https://wiki.vg/Protocol

```
import socket
import struct
import json

def unpack_varint(s):
    d = 0
    for i in range(5):
        b = ord(s.recv(1))
        d |= (b & 0x7F) << 7*i
        if not b & 0x80:
            break
    return d

def pack_varint(d):
    o = b""
    while True:
        b = d & 0x7F
        d >>= 7
        o += struct.pack("B", b | (0x80 if d > 0 else 0))
        if d == 0:
            break
    return o

def pack_data(d):
    h = pack_varint(len(d))
    if type(d) == str:
        d = bytes(d, "utf-8")
    return h + d

def pack_port(i):
    return struct.pack('>H', i)

def get_info(host='localhost', port=25565):

    # Connect
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(5.0)
    s.connect((host, port))

    # Send handshake + status request
    s.send(pack_data(b"\x00\x00" + pack_data(host.encode('utf8')) + pack_port(port) + b"\x01"))
    s.send(pack_data("\x00"))

    # Read response
    unpack_varint(s)     # Packet length
    unpack_varint(s)     # Packet ID
    l = unpack_varint(s) # String length

    d = b""
    while len(d) < l:
        d += s.recv(1024)

    # Close our socket
    s.close()

    # Load json and return
    return json.loads(d.decode('utf8'))

#print(get_info("play.hypixel.net"))
```

Comment: something needs to respond at `s.connect((host, port))` right?

Comment: "Most servers" would appear to have an always-active proxy between you and the actual Minecraft server.